# how to convert java web application for deploying on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications

I have created java web application using struts2 in tomcat server in eclipse. I wanted to deploy it in Google App Engine after created it. so I installed google app engine plugin for eclipse and convert the project for deplyoing on Google App Engine using below method

right click on the project

Google ->App Engine Settings

tic on the box "Use Google App Engine"

after that when I tried to deploy it. it forced me to enter Application ID. When I entered application Id that I created using www.appengine.google.com site, eclipse says

```
Cannot set application ID (appengine-web.xml is missing)
```

error. should I create that xml manually or can I create that automatically? if I ahould create it manually what are the steps to do it.

Comment: I think the appengine-web.xml is the least of your worries.  You should read through the documentation of Google App Engine to see if there are special considerations you need to take into account.  Google App Engine has a number of restrictions you wouldn't have in Tomcat (e.g. no filesystem access).  Struts 2 and any other libraries you're using may use APIs which are incompatible with Google App Engine.

Comment: I just did a quick Google Search to find any such article and found this:  [Creating Struts 2 Application on Google App Engine](http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/creating-struts2-application-on-google-app-engine-gae/)

Answer (score 1):

Struts 2 is compatible with Google App Engine but you need to apply some workarounds. For details, take a look at [Compatibility list of Java technologies with App Engine](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava). Check the information provided for making Struts 2 work in GAE.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Though you used struts, it can be deployed by just giving an app engine xml in its war file as well as you should have added the appengine sdk to this struts project. Then try to deploy it in the localost.

If its success in it surely you can go through deploying it in app engine by just giving the application id in the app-engine xml.

refer:[Java Application Configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Better check for appengine-web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder. If it is existing there then try changing you appengine deploy id. i.e., Create a New ID and deploy into that. If it works fine OK.

Else

Create a new web application project . Better Select it from Google toolbar and copy your files to that new created one. Because in the new created one there will be defaulted appengine-web.xml and try to deploy. Hope it works. Like if it works .

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. 
First I created a HelloWord GAE project, copied the contents of the appengine-web.xml and pasted it in my project that was missing the file. You'll need to change the application ID.

Also, check if you have web.xml file under the WEB-INF folder. that is where you will declare the file that will load once you deploy the application to GAE.